# windows phone 8 emulator showing error when connecting to wcf service

Tags: windows-phone-8

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code while using windows phone 8 emulator

Comment: Please catch the exception and read (and possibly post) its details.

Comment: I think the problem is related to ip address error

Comment: Why do you think so? This is important information for us if you do not want us to blindly guess.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you tried to connect the Windows phone 8 emulator to the localhost wcf service?
this won't work because the emulator is in a virtual machine but there are steps to fix it:

[Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)